# SQL Select Query to search multiple columns and return results in consolidated columns

Tags: sql

We have a table that has claim number, amount, and code for writeoffs.  We do multiple writeoffs per record so we have 4 separate instances labeled as:

```
WOCLAIMNO1,WOAMT1,WOCODE1
WOCLAIMNO2,WOAMT2,WOCODE2
WOCLAIMNO3,WOAMT3,WOCODE3
WOCLAIMNO4,WOAMT4,WOCODE4
```

Currently we need to run 4 separate queries and then just copy and paste them all into one spreadsheet.  We need to get the results of every record that has the WO code including the word `'Warehouse'`.

So if you take the example table below and run query with that criteria you should get the output expected.  What I need is a way to run just one query on all the columns instead of running each query separately, meaning query WO1, then WO2, then WO3, and then WO4 and then combining all the results together manually.

Sample Table
[image]


Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT 
    WOCLAIMNO1 AS WOCLAIMNO, 
    WOAMT1 AS WOAMT, 
    WOCODE1 AS WOCODE
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    WOCODE1 LIKE '%Warehouse%'
UNION ALL
SELECT WOCLAIMNO2, WOAMT2, WOCODE2 FROM mytable WHERE WOCODE2 LIKE '%Warehouse%'
UNION ALL
SELECT WOCLAIMNO3, WOAMT3, WOCODE3 FROM mytable WHERE WOCODE3 LIKE '%Warehouse%'
UNION ALL
SELECT WOCLAIMNO4, WOAMT4, WOCODE4 FROM mytable WHERE WOCODE4 LIKE '%Warehouse%'
```